# AngularJS post Success callback fired even on error

Tags: angularjs

Why is the success callback fired here when the response is 500?

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var user = $scope.user;
    // provide username and password to obtain a token which will be used for api calls
    $http.post('/authenticate', user).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
            $location.path('/');
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.errors = data.errors;
            $scope.message = 'Invalid JSON format, see guidelines for correct format';
            $scope.uploadError = true;
            console.log('ERROR TRUE');
        });
};
```

And the interceptor:

```
angular.module('uploadApp')
       .factory('authInterceptor',

function ($rootScope, $q, $window, $location) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
         $location.path('/login');

      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way angular `$q` promises work is that errors need to be unhandled to continue down the error path - otherwise it assumes that you have corrected the issue or handled the error. So the easiest way is to `throw` the response from your error path, until you get to the point you actually want to handle it.

```
angular.module('uploadApp')
   .factory('authInterceptor',

function ($rootScope, $q, $window, $location) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' +
            $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
   },
   response: function (response) {
     return response || $q.when(response);
   },
   responseError: function(response) {
     if (response.status === 401) {
       $location.path('/login');
     }
     // instead of returning, you should throw, 
     // and when you throw you don't need to wrap, as it will
     // handle it for you.
     //return response || $q.when(response);
     throw response;
   }
  };
});
```

`$q` will ensure that the thrown object is wrapped in the promise call-chain. Note that whenever you return in a `$q` promise it will assume you have handled any issues, unless you throw instead of return. This allows you to have errors in resolvers further down the call-chain that can then be treated as an error.

If throwing isn't your style, you can defer a new promise and return that, then reject it - but that is way less efficient than using the current call-chain.